# Swift how to segue views by tapping a right accessory callout button on a map annotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, mapkit, segue

I am rather new to swift and object oriented programming and I am trying to switch views from a view that contains a map to another view by tapping on a right accessory callout button in the annotation of a pin that is dropped by a long press. In the storyboard, I have created a segue between the two views and assigned the segue with the identifier mapseg. Unfortunately, after trying everything I could find via google I cannot get the segue to occur when I tap the right accessory callout button and have no idea why.The application itself is a tabbed application with three tabs. The view for the second tab is the one that contains the map. Also, I don't know if this could have something to do with it, but the view I am trying to transition from is embedded in a navigation controller. Here is my code for the view that I am trying to transition from.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.MapView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let reuseID = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.enabled=true
        let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        btn.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn as UIView
        return pinView
    }


    @IBAction func dropPin(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            let location = sender.locationInView(self.MapView)
            let locCoord = self.MapView.convertPoint(location, toCoordinateFromView: self.MapView)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = locCoord
            annotation.title = "City Name"
            annotation.subtitle = ""

            self.MapView.removeAnnotations(MapView.annotations)
            self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.MapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)


        }
        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mapseg", sender: self)

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the prepareForSeque code that you used to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` method. And check whether if working

Comment: Ah okay thanks! Do I need to put any code in the body of prepareForSegue function or will it still do what it needs to do if left empty?

Comment: So I tried putting that override function right below the function responsible for executing the segue and it gave me an error message. Upon further inspection I discovered that I had not put the the closing curly brace on the dropPin function, causing the function responsible for segueing to be contained inside the dropPin function which lead to it not being called when the right accessory button was pressed. Now that I've fixed the curly brace and added in the prepareForSegue function it is finally working! Thank you so much! just out of curiosity, what does the prepareForSegue function do?

Comment: It is used if you want to pass any data or object to the UIViewController which is being pushed or presented.

Comment: could you elaborate on the prepareForSeque code to add?